# Joining Tables and Selecting Max Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am working on the following code. What I've done is join the main table (`WORKLOAD_RPTG`) to a `HISTORY` table that will draw out all of the Statuses and Dates of the relevant Requests, Bids, and Contracts.

On the `WORKLOAD_RPTG` table there are `ID` fields for Requests, Bids, and Contracts. Some of these may be NULL, and some may repeat, for instance the same `REQ_ID` may have generated 2 or more contracts with different `CNTRCT_IDs`.

On the `HISTORY` table, there is a `REF_ID` field. Depending on how this is joined to the `WORKLOAD` table, you will pull the status history of the contract, bid or request. I want to pull all of this information on to a single report rather than running it three times and then having to do a bunch of matching and consolidating later.

I want to have just a single row per item (it can have either an Contract/Bid/Request ID or may have all if it went through each process) with the latest Status and Date. Using the query below produces an output like this:

```
CONID - BIDID - REQID - CONSTAT - CONSTAT_DT - BIDSTAT - BIDSTAT_DT ...
ABC12           98765   Opened    01/01/2018   NULL      NULL
ABC12           98765   Closed    02/02/2018   NULL      NULL
ABC34   DEF67   86420   Opened    03/03/2018   Tendered  01/01/2018
ABC34   DEF67   86420   Opened    03/03/2018   Closed    02/02/2018
ABC34   DEF67   86420   Closed    04/04/2018   Tendered  01/01/2018
ABC34   DEF67   86420   Closed    04/04/2018   Closed    02/02/2018
        DEF89   86420   NULL      NULL         Tendered  03/03/2018
```

whereas I'd like it like to look like:

```
CONID - BIDID - REQID - CONSTAT - CONSTAT_DT - BIDSTAT - BIDSTAT_DT ...
ABC12           98765   Closed    02/02/2018   NULL      NULL
ABC34   DEF67   86420   Closed    04/04/2018   Closed    02/02/2018
        DEF89   86420   NULL      NULL         Closed    04/04/2018
```

I tried using the MAX function on the dates, but some Contracts never went to Bid, so the NULLS here would cause these records to drop out of the final report (ie. I'd lose all records of Contract# ABC12 and Bid# DEF89 above).

I suspect that I need to use a subquery, but I'm scratching at head at where to even start. My current query is below:

```
SELECT   WOR.CNTRCT_ID, WOR.BID_ID, WOR.REQ_ID, 
     WOR.PROJ_NM, WOR.BUYER, REQ.ITEM_TYP_CD, 
     CUS.CUST_REQ_CNTCT_NM, 
     TRA1.TRANS_STAT_CD, 
     TRA1.TRANS_STAT_EFF_DT, TRA1.TRANS_STAT_HIST_ID, 
     TRA2.TRANS_STAT_CD, 
     TRA2.TRANS_STAT_EFF_DT, TRA2.TRANS_STAT_HIST_ID, 
     TRA3.TRANS_STAT_CD, 
     TRA3.TRANS_STAT_EFF_DT, TRA3.TRANS_STAT_HIST_ID  
FROM     dbo.REQ REQ, 
     dbo.CUST_REQ CUS, 
     dbo.WORKLOAD_RPTG WOR
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TRANS_STAT_HIST TRA1 ON CNTRCT_ID=TRA1.REF_ID  
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TRANS_STAT_HIST TRA2 ON BID_ID=TRA2.REF_ID  
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TRANS_STAT_HIST TRA3 ON CAST(REQ_ID as CHAR)=CAST(TRA3.REF_ID as CHAR) 
WHERE    REQ.REQ_ID=CUS.REQ_ID 
AND      WOR.CUST_REQ_ID=CUS.CUST_REQ_ID 
AND      WOR.WRK_LD_RPT_STAT = 'WIP' 
ORDER BY 10, 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins.

Comment: Do you have a field (or a combination of fields) in your resultset that can be used to uniquely identify a record ?

Comment: I could combine WOR.CNTRCT_ID, WOR.BID_ID, WOR.REQ_ID and that would give a unique identifier per transaction, so my example above would have unique ids ABC12_98765, ABC34DEF6786420 and _DEF8986420

Comment: Yes this I see. I meant, some column(s) to identify each row in the *original* result set (the first table in your question) ?

Comment: No, if i did, this would've been a lot easier.

Comment: If we want the final results to be deterministic, we need some way to identify these records... Maybe by pulling the `id`s of the records in original tables (`REQ`, `CUST_REQ`, ...) ?